# How to get OWIN HttpListener current connections count?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

I use OWIN selfhost WebAPI at console application and it use HttpListener.

```
_owinApplication = WebApp.Start<Startup>(new StartOptions(baseUri));
```

How i can monitor current active connections in some interval to my application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm create custom middleware and it solve my problem

Comment: I agree. Base question was incorrect and i change solution

Answer (score 0):

Given the nature of HTTP, it's not really possible to monitor "active" connections, since that concept doesn't really exist in HTTP. A client sends a request to your server, and it either fails, or receives a response.

When you see sites report current active users, that number is usually a qualified guess, or perhaps they monitor the clients with the use of websockets, or some sort of ajax polling.

Comment: I'm need count of currently accepted but not return result requests

Comment: Maybe change the Q wording to 'requests' rather than 'connections'

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [DelegatingHandler](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers), register it in the WebApi pipeline and monitor current connections using overridden SendAsync method:

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // TODO: add this request to some static container (like ConcurrentDictionary)

    // let the request to be processed
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    try
    {
        response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
    finally
    {
        // TODO: remove the request from the static container registered above
    }

    // return the response
    return response;
}
```

This way you can not only monitor current connection count, but also all request information, like URL, IP, etc.